# Star Wars now-Legends book where a jedi (Obi-wan?) engages in a duel with metal swords?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, star-wars-legends, obi-wan-kenobi

I recall reading a Star Wars book, I think it was paperback, a few years pre-Disney so several years ago and the book wasn't new at the time but I also don't think the book was more than ten years old at the time of reading.

I believe it followed a jedi master and apprentice, who I recall being Qui-gon and Obi-wan, who were at some point separated.

At least one (the apprentice/obi-wan) was captured by local nobility, and was without his lightsaber, either having had it confiscated or willingly surrendering it at some point. Then he had to duel a local lord (a prince?) with metal swords, which I believe were specifically referred to as broadswords.

Despite being unused to the heavier weapons and facing a much more experienced duelist, Obi-wan successfully adapts to the situation, wins and impresses his opponent, but does not kill him; I don't remember whether the duel was intended to be to the death or not.

Comment: This is probably somewhere in the Jedi Apprentice series by Jude Watson.

Comment: That was the piece I needed! It's Mark of the Crown

Comment: If you post that as an answer I'd accept it

Comment: _""Do you know what this is, Obi-Wan Kenobi?" he asked, flourishing it. "It is a sword," Obi-Wan answered. He had never used the weapon, but he had seen drawings of it at the Temple. It was like a lightsaber, only made of metal._

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your description matches *[The Mark of the Crown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mark_of_the_Crown)*, the fourth book of the *Star Wars: Jedi Apprentice* series by Jude Watson.

> *Prince Beju flushed an angry red. His hand dropped. He strode to the case displaying antique weapons. He lifted the top and drew one out.*
>
> *"Do you know what this is, Obi-Wan Kenobi?" he asked, flourishing it.*
>
> *"It is a sword," Obi-Wan answered. He had never used the weapon, but he had seen drawings of it at the Temple . It was like a lightsaber, only made of metal.*